# Why are inversion of control and the dependency inversion principle not design patterns, while dependency injection is?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dependency-inversion

Why is [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) a design pattern, while [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and [the dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) are both not?

They seem to me design patterns, despite their differences.

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control) seems to be referring to IoC as a design pattern.  I think of IoC as the design pattern, and dependency injection as a particular _implementation_ of that design pattern.

Comment: Dependency injection is the actual implementation of the IOC architecture. An architecture is a way of putting things. Dependency injection is the implementation that makes the things previously mentioned to interact together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between design patterns and design principles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317141/whats-the-difference-between-design-patterns-and-design-principles)

Comment: According to those Wikipedia articles Dependency Injection is not a pattern. It's the name used by Bob Martin in his C++ Report *articles* back in 1994. The DI Principle article you point to though refers to the *SOLID principles*, that's why DI is called a Principle there.